# How can I use git revert to restore all mistakenly deleted files?

Tags: git, revert

I was at the initial commit (`c0`), and I used the command

```
find . -name \*.min.js -type f -delete
```

to delete all minimized JS files in my project, added the change to the staging area and made a commit (`c1`), then pushed it to remote repository. I did some work and made another commit (`c2`) and pushed it to remote repository.

However, I now regret I deleted the files and want to get back all the files. I've searched on the Internet and found the `revert` command; so I ran

```
git revert c0
```

to go back to the commit (`c0`), where I have not deleted the files. I thought that would allow me to see the deleted files again, but no luck. I thought I was doing the right thing...

I am new to Git. Is my basic understanding of `revert` wrong?

Comment: You should be reverting c1, not c0. You want to revert the commit that introduced those deletes. That's c1.

Comment: Why? If I revert to c1, then the changes (deletion) has already been made, so I would not see the deleted files, but if I revert to c0, then the deletion has not been made, so I should revert to c0, right?

Comment: It's called revert, not revert-to. You "revert something", not "revert to something".

Comment: Why don't you give it a try? You can always undo what you do with `git revert` if it turns out it was not what you wanted. `git-revert` is a safe command that only adds news commits to the repo, never removes anything from it.

Comment: ah! it seems my concept about revert is totally wrong, I will give it a try, then report back later, thanks in advance.

Comment: it works!, thanks @PSkocik , now I understand how to use revert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be reverting `c1`, not `c0`. You want to revert the commit that introduced those deletes. That's `c1`.

What you should do now as a good git citizen that doesn't alter history (if you already pushed the c0 revert commit) is

- `git revert c3` (the `c0` revert commit)

and then

- `git revert c1`.

Comment: *[...] as a good git citizen [...]* This phrase alone is worth an upvote :)